# Implications of using a plain string command instead of a function in .bashrc (particularly for PROMPT_COMMAND and PS1)

Tags: bash, shell, performance, prompt, bashrc

I have trouble understanding:

- How is `.bashrc` parsed
- How are bash functions constructed

I try to customize my terminal prompt. My `.bashrc` make use of `PROMPT_COMMAND` like this (it's actually much more complex):

```bsh
function prompt_command {
    PS1="-> "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

I don't like this solution because it clutters my shell namespace with `prompt_command`, while it should be hidden from outside of this file (but I can't use `unset` as that would break the prompt).

So, I figured out I could also set the `PROMPT_COMMAND` in plain text like this:

```bsh
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="-> "'
```

As I said, my prompt command is actually much more complex. So, I'm worried about the efficiency of this alternative.

Although the two methods are functionally equivalent, is there a fundamental difference in the way my `.bashrc` will be parsed and the prompt command will be constructed? Is Bash able to effectively "compile" and "cache" the `prompt_command` as a function object, or is it parsed for each new shell line the same way as if it would be a string?

Comment: I do the same thing: my function name is `__bash_prompt` and I live with it in the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.bashrc` file is parsed once each time a new terminal session is started.

During parsing, the function `prompt_command` is added to the environment variable, but there is no "compilation" step nor "object" constructed as [Bash is a single-pass interpreter language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755688/2291710).

When a new line is typed in my terminal, the `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed, which effectively retrieve `prompt_command` from the environment variables (the same way I could type `prompt_command` in my shell) and execute it line by line. Consequently, the behavior is similar to directly assigning the command to `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Direct assignation should even be (imperceptibly) faster, as it avoid needing to fetch an environment variable.